# Regex - how to handle word boundaries problem?

Tags: regex, preg-match

Say I have the following list:

- banana
- apple(s)

And I have this string:

> This banana is ripe. What happened to the apple(s) yesterday?

I want to iterate through my list and search the string for whole word matches. In the first iteration, I could concatenate word boundaries to the list item:

```
\bbanana\b
```

That would capture the "banana" part of of the above string.

On the second iteration, if I were to do the same concatenation, I would get this:

```
\bapple(s)\b
```

That won't match the `apple(s)` in my string because the closing parenthesis is not a word character.

What could I concatenate to my list items so that I can capture `banana` and `apple(s)` properly? The sub-strings to capture can be anywhere in the string, including at the very start or end of it.

I'm using PHP.

Comment: Use `\B` instead?

Comment: `banana\B` would not work

Comment: Only use `\B` when the last letter is a non-word character, of course

Comment: What you are looking for aren't word boundaries but `(?<!\S)WORD(?!\S)`.

Comment: I'd vote for `(?<!\w)WORD(?!\w)`, those are unambiguous word boundaries, they will always mean "not preceded/followed with a word char".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach.  We can manually simulate word boundary markers, regardless of character type, by using lookarounds.  For a `\b` on the *left*, we can use `(?<=[\s.,;]|^)`, and for `\b` on the right we can use `(?=[\s.,;]|$)`.

```
$input = "This banana is ripe. What happened to the apple(s) yesterday?";
preg_match_all ("/(?<=[\s.,;]|^)apple\(s\)(?=[\s.,;]|$)/", $input, $array);
print_r($array[0]);

Array
(
    [0] => apple(s)
)
```

Regex seems to be a very text-centric tool, and as such, the `\b` word boundary marker is designed to find boundaries between words and non words, rather than boundaries between non words and other non words.

Comment: Punctuation should probably be included in the lookarounds. Otherwise `This is a banana.` will fail.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Do you have something against apples?  I took your advice anyway.

Comment: Speaking of punctuations, what about `?`, `!`, etc.?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I am offering a possible general solution.  I can't read your mind.  You may modify my answer to fit your exact needs.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think you could consider it this way `(?<!\S)apple\(s\)(?!\S(?<![[:punct:]]))`

Comment: The string will be coming from the web, and will be very messy. I'm studying your solution. Worried that I need to list down all possible characters that might immediately precede or follow the word ...

Comment: @revo Good suggestion, but there is always the possibility that the OP would have some punctuation character which is not included in `[:punct:]`.  Which, ironically, sounds the same as "punked."

Comment: Do you mean outside of `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}~`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  It may not be one size fit all.

Comment: Then that's not punctuation mark and the preceding word isn't a word and we are not looking into a sentence. This means OP has not given us enough details.